# fql select: mysterious behave in some cases

Tags: sql, facebook, select, facebook-fql

If I liked twice a user's status, below code returns that id for two times, so I can count how many times I liked a user's status.

```
SELECT uid FROM status WHERE status_id IN (SELECT  object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() LIMIT 5000) ORDER BY uid LIMIT 5000
```

But, the following code returns an uid only one time, even though I liked his status for two times!!! Here I try to filter only those id who are my friends.

```
SELECT uid FROM status WHERE status_id IN (SELECT  object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() LIMIT 5000) and uid in(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 5000
```

Why this above FQL returns each id only one time?
Or if anyone could help me to find  out to count how many times I liked all my friends' status?

Comment: thnkx for quick suggestion.
There is no group by in fql, and count also does not work on a column, I have to count manually as far as I know.
Again, my second query returns each id only once, so can group by help here?

Comment: Oooops, my bad, my eyes are playing tricks on me, I read the whole stuff as 'sql' all the time...  I will remove my remark ;-)